# Calculate simple integral

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

I have to calculate next integral:
$$\int(5\sqrt[4] x + 14\sqrt[4] x^3)dx$$
Please describe all steps and rules used for solving this integral

Comment: I don't know how to calculate $\sqrt[4]x$

Comment: Consider $\sqrt[4]{x}=x^{\frac14}$. That should help

Comment: You have to change it to $x^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First split it up into two integrals:
$$5\int x^{\frac{1}{4}}dx+14\int x^{\frac{3}{4}}dx$$
Then apply the rule
$$\int x^k=\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+C$$
to get
$$5*\frac{4}{5}x^{\frac{5}{4}}+14*\frac{4}{7}x^{\frac{7}{4}}dx+C$$
$$4x^{\frac{5}{4}}+8x^{\frac{7}{4}}dx+C$$
And that should be your answer.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: write your Integrand in the form $$4\cdot x^{1/4}+14\cdot x^{3/4}$$ and use that $$\int x^{n}dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$ if $$n\ne -1$$

Answer (score 1):

the function is $5x^{\frac{1}{4}}+14x^{\frac{3}{4}}$ Can you now use power rule to integrate it ?